# UIScrollview Not Scrolling After setting ContentSize

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I've created a `UIScrollView` programatically, and it is not scrolling:

```
CGRect prevFrame;
        BOOL isFirst = TRUE;
        UIScrollView *view_scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        view_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(650,224*[_cases count]+25*[_cases count]);
        view_scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
        view_scroll.scrollEnabled = YES;
        NSLog(@"%f",view_scroll.contentSize.height);
        [self.view addSubview:view_scroll];
        for(SLSCase* patientCase in _cases){
            SLSCaseCard* caseCard  = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SLSCaseCard" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
            if(isFirst){
                caseCard.frame = CGRectMake(25,25, caseCard.frame.size.width, caseCard.frame.size.height);
                isFirst = FALSE;
            }
            else{
                caseCard.frame = CGRectMake(25, prevFrame.origin.y+caseCard.frame.size.height+25, caseCard.frame.size.width, caseCard.frame.size.height);
            }
            prevFrame = caseCard.frame;
            [view_scroll addSubview:caseCard];
        }
```

As you can see I've set the contentSize and scrollEnabled. It's still not scrolling.

Comment: May be your content size less then your scrollview frame.

Comment: Are you sure that there are items in _cases? Can you see on the screen that the content goes below the bottom of the screen?

Comment: Try assigning the size to a CGSize variable first and check the values to make sure the size is correct

Answer (score 0):

Due to a scrollView feature in auto layout, the contentSize is being redefined.  To solve this problem, you could disable auto layout or set the content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    view_scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(650,224*[_cases count]+25*[_cases count]);
}
```